# When using explicit intent, why doesn't sometimes work (as first parameter) this, but works getApplicationContext() instead? What is the difference?

Tags: java

In android studio, I want to use different component when click on some button.
First, I did like this and it worked:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt = findViewById((R.id.textView));
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userName = editText.getText().toString();

            goToSecondActivity();
        }
    });
}
public void goToSecondActivity()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);

}
```

But in this case, for some reason **this** didn't work and I had to use getApplicationContext() instead, but why didn't work with **this**? As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), this is referencing to the current context i.e mainActivity.

Correct:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt = findViewById((R.id.textView));
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userName = editText.getText().toString();

            //Explicit intent

             //Part where error was
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used `this` in your code as below:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userName = editText.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                                  ^^^^
        }
    });
```

then it produced compilation error because `this` inside the `onClick()` method refers to the instance of the anonymous inner class `View.OnClickListener`, not the outer `Activity` class. You can't use `this` to refer to the outer class from within an inner class. You have to use `getApplicationContext()` or `SomeActivity.this` (assuming your actiity is named SomeActivity) to refer to the context of the outer `Activity` class.

Comment: Understand. But then, if I can't use this to refer to the outer class, then how it worked in first case? There, I also used this inside onClick method.

Comment: In the first case you use `this` inside goToSecondActivity which is outside the anonymous `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand now completely.